# Java - [Swing] Jlist with 2 connected columns

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm making an application where I display in Jlist folders and files from a specified path. I want to add the last modified date of files and folders with sort function by name or date. I'm wondering if I should change the Jlist to Jtable or there is a possible way to do that in Jlist? I`m thinking about using a hash map to keep name and date linked but I don't know how the display of that will work.

[image]

Comment: Yes you should use a JTable.

Comment: Or you can add the date into the list's renderer.

Comment: Don't use a JList. Even with a custom renderer to display the date, it doesn't solve your sorting problem. Use a JTable. You can set up the table to dynamically sort by clicking on the "Name" or "Date" column headers. The DefaultTableModel will allow you to keep the name/date together in the same model. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784). It includes a `JTable` (as suggested by @weisj & camickr).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have done JTable as you suggested but I can clearly see another problem and I can not solve it. When I sort my files and folders by name or date it displays a sorted table but files are in the same spot. Example: I want to go to the Windows folder which is on ss in last row. When I sort the last happens to be "swapfile.sys" and when I click it, It takes me to the windows folder. Any Idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Note that a lot of the sample code I linked to is irrelevant to this immediate problem. Just try to create a table using files in `user.home`.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem with [convertRowIndexToModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29)